# Redirects to login AuthServer Spring oauth2 not found

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0

I have an AuthorizationServer with spring in one app and I want to authorize and authenticate calls with Bearer tokens in my api rest.

The comunications goes well ( I think ) but when the token is valid shows:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1466606797251,
  "status": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "message": "No message available",
  "path": "/api/authorizationServer/login"
}
```

when token is invalid saids:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_token",
  "error_description": "Access token expired: cc281c6a-aeef-401c-879a-624c94058c7b"
}
```

Why shows not found?

EDIT:

My rest service is pretty simple:

Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

end point:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello",
            method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello User!";
    }
}
```

config:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: client
      clientSecret: secret
      accessTokenUri: http://localhost:8080/api/v1/secure/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:8080/api/v1/secure/oauth/authorize
      clientAuthenticationScheme: header
    resource:
      tokenInfoUri: http://localhost:8080/api/v1/secure/oauth/check_token
server:
  port: 8082
  contextPath: /api/v1/auth
```

Comment: You better take a look on where the exception is comming from (cause one might be throwned then catched by spring to generate this 404). With just this informations it will be pretty hard to find the root cause.

Comment: I'm sure I miss something I dont have any endpoint /login on authserver neither api rest, I supose that because of that shows 404 but I want redirect to the api rest.

Comment: How do you endUp on the `/login` page then? If you are just requesting random page with a valid token, it is a normal and wanted behavior to return 404.
But you also encounter an "invalid_token" on this resource because i guess the token is checked by Spring BEFORE trying to reach the actual resource, and if you have an invalid token, the request is stopped with an error.

Comment: you were right spring validates token before Indeed when I call to : http://localhost:8082/api/v1/auth/hello without header authotization it 'works' and response not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me added:

```
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer
                .checkTokenAccess("permitAll()");
    }
```

On AuthServer and:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
    protected static class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Order(2)
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
            ;
        }

        @Order(1)
        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web
                    .ignoring()
                    .antMatchers("/api/**");
        }

    }
```

on ResourceServer

Answer (score 0):

As my comment says:

On an incoming request, Spring first check the token validity. 
If token is not valid you are thrown away with an `invalid_token` message.
If token is valid, Spring forward the request to the controller. But in your case, there is no url mapped on `/login`, so you encounter a 404.

It is a wanted behavior to check the token validity before even check if the URL exists, and this is the reason why you are encontering `invalid_token` on non existing URL.